# Why are my images not uploaded?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am using laravel with bootstrap file input plugin to upload multiple images with drag and drop. But the images are not uploaded on server. I have given permission to folders. 
Here is my code for html :

```
<input id="file-upload1" name="gallery[]" type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/bmp, image/jpg" class="" multiple>
```

Here is my code for javascript :

```
if( $('#file-upload1').length ) {
        $('#file-upload1').fileinput({
            uploadUrl: '#',
            allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg','png','gif'],
            showUpload: false,
            showRemove: false,
            browseClass: "button-shadow btn",
            initialPreview: imgArr,
            overwriteInitial: false,
            initialPreviewConfig: configArr,
            //maxFileSize: 100,
            //initialCaption: "The Moon and the Earth"

        });
    }
```

Your help would be critical at the hour of need.

Comment: Your `uploadUrl` looks wrong.  Also we'd need to see your server side code

Comment: I want to put the upload url such that the images are uploaded with the form where the input with id file-upload1 is included in the form. Server side code just reads the files in above field. Stating that code would not make any difference because when i check request just after submission, it does not have images. hope this info helps.

Comment: You are checking `$request->files('gallery')`?  According to the docs, `uploadUrl` should only be set if you want to upload via ajax which you do not want so I'd remove that entirely.

Comment: If i remove that , drag and drop goes away.

Comment: Just read more of the docs, what you want is impossible.  If you need to upload multiple images, it needs to be done via ajax (not with the rest of the form).  See #2 here http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#usage-modes

Comment: Nice insight, thanks